# Update the time since upload of an item in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a news app made with flutter and I am unable to figure out how to calculate the time difference between two times.

For example :- The news was posted ...
10 minutes ago, 5 hours ago, 1 year ago, 10 years ago, etc.

Please help me with this problem by suggesting me a solution.

Comment: Maybe this answer is similar with your code [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873902/how-to-display-time-ago-like-youtube-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using duration package?
https://pub.dev/packages/duration
You can check its documentation and see if it matches your needs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).